# How do I make my character run around the camera in third person?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

I'm working on a third-person run-around game and there's a specific kind of movement I've wanted to achieve but I'm having trouble even imagining how it would work, let alone actually coding it.

Essentially, when holding left or right, I want the player to orbit the camera. Such a camera effect can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bc8T.jpg). That's exactly what I want to achieve.

Here's my movement and camera code so far. I image I'll need to use  the camera's Y rotation to achieve this but my tests haven't worked out. Any input would be appreciated!

**Movement:**

```
public int speed = 10;
public int rotationSpeed = 10;

public CharacterController cc;
Vector2 input;
Vector3 moveDir;
Vector3 lookDir;

Vector3 forward;
Transform camTransform;

public Transform model;

void Start () {
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    camTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void GetInput() {
    input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
}

void CalculateForward()
{

}

void Move()
{
    moveDir.x = input.x;
    moveDir.z = input.y;

    if(moveDir.magnitude > 1)
    {
        moveDir.Normalize();
    }

    Vector3 rotatedDir = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);
    rotatedDir = new Vector3(rotatedDir.x, 0, rotatedDir.z);
    rotatedDir = rotatedDir.normalized * moveDir.magnitude;

    cc.Move(rotatedDir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void ApplyGravity()
{

}

    void FaceDir()
{
    if (moveDir != Vector3.zero)
    {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
            transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(-moveDir),
            Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed
        );
    }
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetInput();
    //ApplyGravity();
    Move();
    FaceDir();
    ApplyGravity();
}
```

}

**Camera:**

```
 [SerializeField]
private float distanceAway;
[SerializeField]
private float distanceUp;
[SerializeField]
private float smooth;
[SerializeField]
private Transform follow;

private Vector3 targetPosition;

private void Start()
{
    follow = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    targetPosition = follow.position + follow.up * distanceUp - follow.forward * distanceAway;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

    transform.LookAt(follow);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Normally, one wants the camera to orbit the player. You mean you want the camera in a fixed position, and left or right will automatically move the player around a circumference and the camera will constantly looking at the player?

Comment: @AustinWBryan Yes, that's exactly what I want. I want the player to move in a circumference around the camera when left or right is held, rather than moving left/right with a panning camera, which is what my code above does. Sorry for the confusion!

**Edit** [I added another gif that demonstrates it better](https://imgur.com/a/S5TJTSQ), hopefully that demonstrates the character running "around" the camera better.

Answer (score 0):

Movement around a circle is always in a direction tangential to the circle, so with each update you want to:

- Set the Y rotation of the player to be looking directly at the Y axis of the camera
- rotate the player 90 degrees left or right (depending on the direction you want to go)
- move the player forward a distance that will depend on the speed with which you would like them to move

Remember it's impossible to traverse a circle perfectly because there are infinitely many points on a circle but this approach will approximate it well enough.

Comment: This helps a ton, I was having trouble with the theory of how it could work. Thank you so much! I'm going to give it another go tonight.